# ftp.ControlChannelIOException: Connection reset(Talend/Java)

Tags: java, ftp, talend, connection-reset

I have a requirement to pull the files and push the files from FTP Server but I am getting the below error while pulling/fetching the files from/into FTP server. I am using Talend Open Source Data Integration Tool, also tried using custom java code and getting the same error. While I am able to pull and fetch the files using FileZilla FTP Client. I am getting the error when I am trying to pull and push the files.

Error Start ..

> com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ControlChannelIOException: Connection reset
>     at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.readLine(FTPControlSocket.java:1014)
>     at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.readReply(FTPControlSocket.java:1049)
>     at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.sendCommand(FTPControlSocket.java:973)
>     at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.createDataSocketPASV(FTPControlSocket.java:807)
>     at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.createDataSocket(FTPControlSocket.java:563)
>     at
>   com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.setupDataSocket(FTPClient.java:2561)
>     at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.dir(FTPClient.java:3468)  at
>   vikas_sir.ftp_salesforce_and_vice_verasa_0_1.FTP_Salesforce_AND_Vice_Verasa.tFTPFileList_2Process(FTP_Salesforce_AND_Vice_Verasa.java:488)    at
>   vikas_sir.ftp_salesforce_and_vice_verasa_0_1.FTP_Salesforce_AND_Vice_Verasa.tFTPConnection_1Process(FTP_Salesforce_AND_Vice_Verasa.java:396)
>     at
>   vikas_sir.ftp_salesforce_and_vice_verasa_0_1.FTP_Salesforce_AND_Vice_Verasa.runJobInTOS(FTP_Salesforce_AND_Vice_Verasa.java:1085)     at
>   vikas_sir.ftp_salesforce_and_vice_verasa_0_1.FTP_Salesforce_AND_Vice_Verasa.main(FTP_Salesforce_AND_Vice_Verasa.java:942)

Error End ..

I have already tried the below things :

1. Allowed java application for my firewall e.g java.exe, javaw.exe and etc.
2. Also tried by disabling the firewall.
3. used **netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable** command as admin.
4. Disabled my antivirus.
5. Also added TLS1.1 and TLS 1.2 into .ini file.
6. Also tried in different Local Machines.
7. Tried by writing custom java code.

Below is link to the screenshot of the talend job :

[Talend Job to pull the files from FTP server](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Grjdd7R0wwc3BGNTR3MFJkU1E/view?usp=sharing)

Also when I am trying another FTP credentials, not getting(Can push and pull the files from/into FTP Server) any error.

Please let me know what/where I am doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Amit